# how to get elements, attributes and its values from xml?

Tags: php, xml, parsing

Here is my sample xml file. how can i get each elements, attributes and their values. i want all versions' code and name, all release' code and name and all brands' code and name?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PLM_University namespace="DS">
  <ALL_VERSIONS>
    <version code="1" name="V1" description="Version for CLS Products">
      <RELEASES_LIST>
        <release code="7" name=".7" rank="5" description="">
          <BRAND_LIST>
            <BRAND code="WLS" name="Companion">
              <SOLUTIONS_LIST>
                <SOLUTION code="WLS_STU" name="Companion Learning Space" />

              </SOLUTIONS_LIST>
            </BRAND>
          </BRAND_LIST>
        </release>
      </RELEASES_LIST>
    </version>
    <version code="10" name="Matrix10" description="Version for Matrix Products">
        <RELEASES_LIST>
        <release code="6" name=".6" rank="1" description="">
          <BRAND_LIST>
            <BRAND code="ENOVIA" name="ENOVIA Collaborative Innovation">
               <SOLUTIONS_LIST>
                <SOLUTION code="ENOV_MX1" name="ENOVIA MatrixOne" />

               </SOLUTIONS_LIST>
             </BRAND>
           </BRAND_LIST>
          </release>
         <release code="7" name=".7" rank="2" description="">
          <BRAND_LIST>
             <BRAND code="ENOVIA" name="ENOVIA Collaborative Innovation">
               <SOLUTIONS_LIST>
                 <SOLUTION code="ENOV_MX1" name="ENOVIA MatrixOne" />

              </SOLUTIONS_LIST>
            </BRAND>
           </BRAND_LIST>
         </release>
            <release code="8" name=".8" rank="3" description="">
          <BRAND_LIST>
            <BRAND code="ENOVIA" name="ENOVIA Collaborative Innovation">
              <SOLUTIONS_LIST>
            <SOLUTION code="ENOV_MX1" name="ENOVIA MatrixOne" />
              </SOLUTIONS_LIST>
            </BRAND>
          </BRAND_LIST>
        </release>
    </RELEASES_LIST>
    </version>
</ALL_VERSIONS>
</PLM_University>
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres an easy solution you can work with:

```
<?php
//Load xml file and than json encode/decode it into an array.
$a = json_decode(json_encode((array) simplexml_load_file('path_to_your_xml.xml'),1);

//Loop the array creating a return array
$return = array();
foreach($a['ALL_VERSIONS']['version'] as $key=>$value){
    $return[$key]['code'] = $value['@attributes']['code'];
    $return[$key]['name'] = $value['@attributes']['name'];

    if(is_array($value['RELEASES_LIST']['release']) && isset($value['RELEASES_LIST']['release'][0]['BRAND_LIST']['BRAND']['@attributes']['code'])){
        //Loop sup versions
        foreach($value['RELEASES_LIST']['release'] as $key2=>$sub){
            $return[$key][$key2]['RELEASES_LIST'] = array(
                                            'core'=>$sub['@attributes']['code'],
                                            'name'=>$sub['@attributes']['name']);
            $return[$key][$key2]['BRAND_LIST'] = array(
                                            'brand'=>$sub['BRAND_LIST']['BRAND']['@attributes']['code'],
                                            'brand_name'=>$sub['BRAND_LIST']['BRAND']['@attributes']['name']);
        }

    }else{
    $return[$key]['RELEASES_LIST'] = array(
                                            'core'=>$value['RELEASES_LIST']['release']['@attributes']['code'],
                                            'name'=>$value['RELEASES_LIST']['release']['@attributes']['name']);
    $return[$key]['BRAND_LIST'] = array(
                                            'brand'=>$value['RELEASES_LIST']['release']['BRAND_LIST']['BRAND']['@attributes']['code'],
                                            'brand_name'=>$value['RELEASES_LIST']['release']['BRAND_LIST']['BRAND']['@attributes']['name']);
    }
}

print_r($return);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [code] => 1
            [name] => V1
            [RELEASES_LIST] => Array
                (
                    [core] => 7
                    [name] => .7
                )

            [BRAND_LIST] => Array
                (
                    [brand] => WLS
                    [brand_name] => Companion
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [code] => 10
            [name] => Matrix10
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [RELEASES_LIST] => Array
                        (
                            [core] => 6
                            [name] => .6
                        )

                    [BRAND_LIST] => Array
                        (
                            [brand] => ENOVIA
                            [brand_name] => ENOVIA Collaborative Innovation
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [RELEASES_LIST] => Array
                        (
                            [core] => 7
                            [name] => .7
                        )

                    [BRAND_LIST] => Array
                        (
                            [brand] => ENOVIA
                            [brand_name] => ENOVIA Collaborative Innovation
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [RELEASES_LIST] => Array
                        (
                            [core] => 8
                            [name] => .8
                        )

                    [BRAND_LIST] => Array
                        (
                            [brand] => ENOVIA
                            [brand_name] => ENOVIA Collaborative Innovation
                        )

                )

        )

)
*/
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("data.xml");

foreach($xml->ALL_VERSIONS->version as $child)
{

    echo "Version code : ".$child['code'];
    echo "Version name : ".$child['name'];

    foreach($child->RELEASES_LIST->release as $releaseChild)
    {
        echo "release code : ".$releaseChild['code'];
        echo "release name : ".$releaseChild['name'];

        echo "brand code : ".$releaseChild->BRAND_LIST->BRAND['code'];
        echo "brand name : ".$releaseChild->BRAND_LIST->BRAND['name'];
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

in php you can use DOMDocument

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

on php

for example :

```
  <?php
   $handle = fopen("1.xml", "rb");
   $xml= '';
   while (!feof($handle)) {
       $xml .= fread($handle, 8192);
   }
   fclose($handle);

    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadXML($xml);
    $books = $dom->getElementsByTagName('book');
    foreach ($books as $book) {
       echo $book->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
    }
  ?>
```

see this page for more example http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

Comment: i am using file, not string. can you please tell me other way to do it?

Comment: @Alpa you can use fopen and fread for make a string from file.see changed answer

Comment: @mohammadmohsenipur you dont need to build the $xml string you can simple use `$doc->load('1.xml');`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone yes at first i thought input is string but now he told me it is file i want show him can use fopen,... for make a string from file